# "unresolved import" when calling functions across modules in Rust 2018

Tags: rust

Here is the file tree of my demo project:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
    ├── lib.rs
    ├── ooo.rs
    └── xxx.rs
```

In `lib.rs`:

```
mod xxx;
mod ooo;
```

In `xxx.rs`:

```
pub fn hello() {
    println!("hello!");
}
```

In `ooo.rs`:

```
use xxx::hello;

pub fn world() {
    hello();
    println!("world!");
}
```

When I execute `cargo build`, it doesn't succeed:

```
   Compiling ooo v0.1.0 (/Users/eric/ooo)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `xxx`
 --> src/ooo.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use xxx::hello;
  |     ^^^ Could not find `xxx` in `{{root}}`
```

I know that if I use `super::ooo::hello` instead of `ooo::hello`, it will succeed, but is there any way I can use `ooo::hello` and succeed?

For example, this works in the `redis-rs` project in `src/client.rs` where `connection` and `types` are the modules in this crate:

```
use connection::{connect, Connection, ConnectionInfo, ConnectionLike, IntoConnectionInfo};
use types::{RedisFuture, RedisResult, Value};
```

Comment: The example you've provided works just fine.  Either you've pasted the wrong code, or you're omitting something important.

Comment: The answer below is right.. I use the 2018 edition, the old way won't work..

Comment: The opposite is true; the old way does work with this code.  Using a beta feature and not mentioning it counts as omitting something important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using the beta version of the 2018 edition of Rust rather than the stable release.  In the new version, you need to explicitly mark imports from the current crate with the `crate` keyword:

```
use crate::xxx::hello;
```

See [the section on "path clarity" in the edition guide](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html) for more details.

Comment: Not sure if things have changed since then, but I'm still having the same issue as OP, even when using the `crate` prefix, in following your answer. I have a file called `helpers.rs` in the same directory as my `main.rs`. `helpers.rs` has a simple module defined in it, and I wish to use one of the functions from that module in my `main.rs`. The first line of my `main.rs` is `use crate::helpers;`, but when I try to compile I get the error message "no 'helpers' in the root (E0432)".

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have caused it by not introducing it in the main.rs。I'll use my experience as an example。
Below is my file directory。

```
└── src
    ├── console.rs
    ├── main.rs
    └── sbi.rs
```

I want to introduce the functions in the sbi.rs in the console.rs.
The first ，you should do is import sbi.rs module in your main.rs

in main.rs

```
mod sbi;
```

in console.rs

```
use crate::sbi::console_putchar;
```

in sbi.rs

```
    pub fn console_putchar(c: usize) {
    #[allow(deprecated)]
    sbi_rt::legacy::console_putchar(c);
}
```

If you're compiling a lab project，There are no main.rs file。You need to import the module first in the file you want to import

in console.rs

```
mod sbi;
use crate::sbi::console_putchar;
```

in sbi.rs

```
    pub fn console_putchar(c: usize) {
    #[allow(deprecated)]
    sbi_rt::legacy::console_putchar(c);
}
```

That's how I solved this problem, I hope it helps you